# Problems with aircrack-ng, ALFA usb not working/causing internet to shut down?

Tags: networking, security, wifi, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I apologise if this is basic troubleshooting. I bought a AWUS036NEH, which is recognised and properly appearing in Device Manager in Windows 10.

I am using Debian 10x 64 bit, on Windows 10 via VMWare Workstation. I installed the Windows 10 driver for the ALFA device. My PC has an ethernet connection from a BT wifi disc.

I am using VmWare Workstation, Kali 2020 64 bit. When I go to VM, Removable Devices, I am given the choice to connect my ALFA device to Kali, but disconnecting it from the host. Unfortunately, doing so disconnects me from the internet on my PC.

Connecting the device to Kali (which disables my internet on PC)

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0
PHY Interface Driver Chipset
phy0 wlan0 rt2800usb Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070
(mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
(mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

I went to Device Manager, and right clicked on my 802.11n USB wireless card, have altered the Country region (2.4GHz); to see if that would help it would seem not....? using anything other than 0,1 or 5, (2,3,4,6,7), my internet cuts out. I am not sure how changing the channl of my wireless card would affect my internet, when it is a plug-in/USB device? I thought perhaps there was a conflict between for Kali, but I am totally basically lost.

Also, when I connect the USB wireless card to VMWare, then ran `/usr/sbin/airmon-ng` and I got:

```
phy3    wlan0           rt2800usb       Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070
```

Then I ran `sudo  airmon-ng start wlan0` which gave me:

```
PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

phy3    wlan0           rt2800usb       Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070
                (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy3]wlan0 on [phy3]wlan0mon)
                (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy3]wlan0)
```

I then ran `sudo airodump-ng wlan0mon`, left it running it for 15 minutes...totally blank.

```
Interface wlan0mon:                                                                                                                                                                                               
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
```

Where am I going wrong? Why is my internet crashing on my PC? Can I have my internet, and use aircrack at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

1 quick question: When you connect ANY USB device to your VM is it still available for your host machine? The answer is NO. The same as your wireless adapter. You cannot have the same device connected to 2 different machines, even if it's a VM it's another whole different machine.

Comment: yes, I am aware of that. But as I have said, the wifi adapter is USB, my wifi has an ethernet cable, directly connected to my computer.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: I know it should be a comment, but I had no enough rep at the time.